# Sending Email using MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, email

I want to send email using an MVC 3 application. I have a user table named Reviewer in a database with email addresses. What I want is when I select 2-3 users from the table on the view using checkboxes, the email address for each user should be inserted automatically into the "Textbox" on the feedback view page, but it's not working. It's taking the value of `Webmail.Send()` from the controller instead of the feedback form page. Any ideas?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Feedback(string email, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
            WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
            WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
            WebMail.UserName = "myemail@gmail.com";
            WebMail.Password = "*******123";
            WebMail.From = "myemail@gmail.com";
            WebMail.Send(
                    "senderemail@yahoo.com",
                    subject,
                    body,
                    email 
                );

            return RedirectToAction("FeedbackSent");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", ex.ToString());
        }

        return View();
    }
```

This is the View page of Feedback:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Your e-mail:</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("email")</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Subject:</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBox("subject")</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Body:</td>
        <td>@Html.TextArea("body")</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it's taking the value from the controller? That the "from" email is `myemail@gmail.com` instead of what was entered in the form?

Comment: i mean when i send email it goes from "myemail@gmail.com" to "senderemail@yahoo.com". But i want to send email from "myemail@gmail.com" to the person(s) that i select from the check box list on the feedback page.

Comment: I can't find where are you selecting the destination emails... your controller just have one email as parameter and the others are harcoded.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this:

```
WebMail.Send(
    email,
    subject,
    body
);
```

Or you could eliminate the line:

```
WebMail.From = "myemail@gmail.com";
```

And use:

```
WebMail.Send(
    email,
    subject,
    body,
    from: "myemail@gmail.com"
);
```

More on the `WebMail` class and what the arguments to `WebMail.Send` are can be found here: [`WebMail` Class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webmail%28v=vs.99%29.aspx).